# Create new column which value is the subtraction of 2 columns on different tables

Tags: mysql

[image]I have done a table named invoice and on this table I would like to create a column PROFIT.  To obtain the value of PROFIT I need to subtract the column amountUsd from table invoice MINUS the value amountUsd on table carriersPayments.  Both tables have the exactly same column loadNumber.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following `SELECT`:

```
SELECT i.*, i.amountUsd - cp.amountUsd AS PROFIT 
FROM invoice i INNER JOIN carriersPayments cp ON i.loadNumber = cp.loadNumber
```

To substract multiple carriers payments you can use the following query:

```
SELECT i.id, i.loadNumber, i.amountUsd - SUM(cp.amountUsd) AS PROFIT 
FROM invoice i INNER JOIN carriersPayments cp ON i.loadNumber = cp.loadNumber
GROUP BY i.id, i.loadNumber, i.amountUsd
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=283dab5af30e7bd013e9aacbdfe723d3)

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly.  But what if we have 2 or more carriersPayments with the same loadNumber.  Could it be possible to substract more than one carriersPayments to 1 invoice?

Comment: @user1757383 - yes this is possible. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. It also worked perfectly.  You made my day. Thanks.